# Godaddy and heroku, pointing domain

Tags: heroku, dns

I have a domain from godaddy and an app hosted on heroku. Now I can access my app by `domain.com` or `www.domain.com` or `domain.herokuapp.com` i want to remove the last version and `domain.herokuapp.com` to become `domain.com`.

I have name.com and www.name.com worked but i want to get rid off name.herokuapp.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rack-cannonical-host` https://github.com/tylerhunt/rack-canonical-host to force anyone visiting `domain.herokuapp.com` to be redirected to `domain.com` or `www.domain.com`. I use this for CodeTriage so if you visit http://issuetriage.com it will redirect to https://www.codetriage.com. Here [is the code in the project that sets up the redirect](https://github.com/codetriage/codetriage/blob/b5aabbc2ac149359cb17843a0e634fbe692a693d/config/application.rb#L23).

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) may helps (Custom Domain Names for Apps in Heroku).
You can also redirect www.domain.com to domain.com in GoDaddy

Comment: I made all that things but i don't want to have domain.herokuapp.com still available.